# Thunderbird : always the same specific email as sender

Tags: thunderbird

I receive mail from multiple adresses, let say :
aurelien@*aaa*.com
aurelien@*bbb*.com
aurelien@*ccc*.com

*bbb* and *ccc* adresses are aliases of the main *aaa* adress and they all are added as "identity" inside Thunderbird.

When i answer to someone who adressed a message to *bbb* or *ccc*, i would like to always have *aaa* adresse as the sender, otherwise *bbb* and *ccc* will be rejected by the smtp server.

I can't find a way to do so in Thunderbird parameters.
I hope i am clear !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Thunderbird, I have used the add-on
[Correct Identity](https://github.com/dennisverspuij/tb-correctidentity).

Installing this add-on in Thunderbird has solved this identity
problem for me.

Note that Thunderbird Support thread
[Bug 327713 From: address in reply is always set using X-Account-Key: header, even though mail folder owner account does not use "Global Inbox"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=327713),
was opened 17 years ago (!) and not yet solved.
The Thunderbird developers still have not understood the problem.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, thanks !